# Electrical properties of LEDs when overdriven

Tags: led

I've found in a batch of LEDs that they are very variable in the current and/or voltage that they can withstand. Over a period of 24 hours, a proportion will become significantly dimmer, and even slightly change colour. I expect this is because of poor manufacturing.

I would like to quantify the results of such tests so I can determine a voltage/current that for example 99% of specimens can be reliably driven at. However, optical measuring equipment is very expensive, and I am wondering:

- Would the electrical characteristics for the partially damaged LEDs change after being overdriven? And if so, what would the changes be?
- If electrical characteristics could pre-determine if an LED is more susceptible to blowing?

I am considering plotting forward voltage vs forward current to investigate, (either using an oscilloscope and signal generator, or making some hardware that would facilitate collecting the results for analysis) but statistically quantifying the results would be hard if I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: Buy a photodiode and an op-amp - this will measure optical output changes quite accurately - not expensive!!

Comment: I suspect the colour change and reduced output might be due (in part) to the heat produced melting/burning the plastic encapsulation. If your exceeding the manufacturer's specs during your testing you can't blame them for poor manufacturing. Any component can be made to fail if it is stressed enough.

Comment: Which supplier and part number? How are you driving them?

Comment: Brand is unknown, the only spec I have is a voltage range. Many are blowing well below the upper limit. I'm driving them with a regulated voltage supply and a series potentiometer. I have used two methods: adjust the pot to achieve a voltage across the LED, and also adjust to achieve a certain current (where the voltage is within the spec range). In both cases the supply voltage is over double the voltage across the LED

Comment: Buy devices with a proper spec. and make sure that you run them within spec. You shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: What colour are they, and what have you been told the voltage range is? Could you provide a picture?

Comment: Tell us more re what voltage and current you expect them to be rated at and WHY you have this expectation. Read what Olin says. A photo and specs that you think apply and why MAY help. If they are not utter junk then NONE of a batch should change noticeably in 24 hours if driven in spec. It sound like you are vastly over rating them. Look at the V-U curve in LED spec sheets and note the flattish I rise with V increase then a kne and increasingly more vertical curve. Note where their max operating points lie. If you are well up the more vertical part of curve you are probably in the death zone.

Comment: Don Oxygen mask and descend to base camp at once and acclimatise. What are you trying to do with them. Where did you get them. How many have you got? If you are within the sound of [Bow Bells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bow_bells)  more or less (give a mile or 20) there will be many places to buy cheap LEDs with known specs. These need to be free and in large volume to be worth your while.

Comment: Long ago when LEDs were new you could buy "bargin" bags of LEDs. They were rejects from the makers and performance was random in most values except Vf, which was always higher than good LEDs. Each one had to have it's resistor hand picked....ahhhh the good old days.

Answer (score 8):

You seem to have some basic misconceptions.

First, the voltage spec of LEDs doesn't tell you the fixed voltage you should run them at.  It tells you the voltage range you will get when running the LED at some current.  LEDs are diodes, so at the normal operating point the voltage varies little as a function of current.  Flip this around and you see that the current will vary a lot with a small change in voltage.  LEDs are so sensitive to voltage variations, and the exact voltage to achieve full brightness can vary enough, so that you can't usefully drive a LED with a fixed voltage because the current will be too unpredictable.  Think of these devices as being driven with specified current, and the voltage just comes along for the ride.  The voltage spec is there only to give you some idea what that voltage will be.

Second, when you exceed maximum specs on any device, it is grossly unfair to blame its resulting failure on bad manufacturing.  The point of a spec is to tell you what you can do to the device so that it will continue to meet its other specs and not fail.

You left out the all-important information of what size and type of LEDs these are and the actual voltage and current you are driving them with.  If they are losing brightness and changing color from only 24 hours of use, then you are overdriving them.  That is exactly the kind of failures to be expected from moderate overdriving.

If you have typical T1-3/4 LEDs, then assume they are rated for 20 mA.  Most discrete LEDs are rated for 20 mA, some more.  Some very small suface mount LEDs are rated for less.  The voltage at full rated current is usually a bit over 3 V for blue, about 2.1 V for green, and around 1.8 V for red.  Again, that is not a spec to drive the LED at, but what you are likely to end up at when driven properly at full brightness.

LEDs intended for lighting are a different matter.  These come in more expensive packages designed to allow for heat removal.  As a result, they can be driven harder for the same size.  There are many proprietary packages, and units that look similar can actually be quite different.  Some can take 100s of mA or more if kept at the right temperature, but you really need a datasheet to know how to use them effectively but still not damage them.  These kind of high performance LEDs are tuned closer to the edge with less wiggle room past the specs.